# Magento2.4.5: How to setup magento compatibility tool on local?

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.5

I want to set up a Magento compatibility tool locally to see if my modules are compatible with magento2.4.5 and php8.1,
are there any other extensions or tools available for checking compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are some tools,
First is the Magento compatibility tool which you can download in your local environment, Here are the commands

**Run this command in your**

> /var/www/html/

```
composer create-project magento/upgrade-compatibility-tool uct --repository https://repo.magento.com
```

after that open terminal in the newly created folder uct and gives permissions

```
chmod +x ./uct/bin/uct
```

And last here are some commands in this Magento blog you can check

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/upgrade-compatibility-tool/use-upgrade-compatibility-tool/run.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you :

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/upgrade-compatibility-tool/use-upgrade-compatibility-tool/run.html

Some of tools I will tell you :

> - PHP8.1
> - Composer 2
> - Elastic Search
> - My SQL